# play sound when counter hits 0 within an event listener

Tags: javascript, dom-events, html5-audio

I decided to post a new question again because my previous one was a bit convoluted.

so i have this timer on a loop.

```
let cc = 3;

(function count(cc) {
 document.getElementById("cco").innerHTML = cc;
 if (cc > 0)
   setTimeout(function() { count(--cc); }, 1000);
 if(cc ==0)
 setTimeout(function() {
 cc = 4
 count(--cc); }, 1000);
})(3);
```

and i have this event listener for several audio buttons that may play at the same time.

```
parent.addEventListener('click',player2, false)

function player2(e){
  if(e.target !== e.currentTarget){

    let clickedSound = e.target.id

      if (soundOb[clickedSound].duration > 0 && soundOb[clickedSound].paused) {
        let counter = document.getElementById('cco').innerHTML;

//only play any sound when the timer (cc = 0) hits 0

            soundOb[clickedSound].play()
            soundOb[clickedSound].loop = true;

        } else {

        soundOb[clickedSound].pause();
        soundOb[clickedSound].currentTime = 0;

        }


  }
}
```

i need the sound to play only when the counter hits 0. for tempo/beet reasons.
i can only rely on an external counter cus not all audio files have the same length.

thank you

Comment: I'm not sure where you want to go with this but
do you mean something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/9r1en0y4/8/ ?

Comment: well, not exactly, more like this https://antoniofrom1984.github.io/soundgrid/

so you hit play on the sound buttons but it only plays when the counter is at 0

Comment: Why not add a boolean? https://jsfiddle.net/35nzsakL/3/